# CI Migrations Not Inserting Data

Tags: php, codeigniter

My codeigniter migrations are not inserting the $data, It creates tables OK but just not adding the data I set. No errors show up not sure what is wrong I had a look at user guide. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/migration.html

```
private function _user_group() {
      if(!$this->db->table_exists('user_group')) {
         $this->dbforge->add_field(array(
         'user_group_id' => array(  
            'type' => 'int',
            'constraint' => 11,
            'null' => false
         ),

         'name' => array(
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'constraint' => 64,
            'null' => false
         ),

         'permission' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'null' => false
         )

         ));

         $this->dbforge->add_key('user_group_id', true);
         $this->dbforge->create_table('user_group', true);

         $data = array(
            array('user_group_id' => '1',
            'name' => 'Administration'),
            array('user_group_id' => '10',
            'name' => 'Demonstration')
         );
         //$this->db->insert('user_group', $data); I tried both
         $this->db->insert_batch('user_group', $data);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved My Own Problem I Had To Add Double Quotes ""

```
$data = array(
array('user_group_id' => "1",
'name' => "Administration"),

array('user_group_id' => "10",
'name' => "Demonstration")
);
```